# Can traveling at relativistic speeds change your shape in your resting reference frame?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames

Let's say I start off standing on Earth, and I then accelerate up to half the speed of light. Let E be Earth's resting reference frame and V be the reference frame where I'm stationary at the end. Do I have the same shape in E before I started as in V after accelerating? Is it possible that in the process of accelerating I rotated in spacetime, so that I have the same shape in E before and after accelerating?

Answer (score 2):

No. You always see yourself as having the same shape.

The differences that two observers see in each other have nothing to do with any acceleration needed to change from one frame to another. It is all caused by speed.

Two rocket pass by each other at high speed. Each sees the other as short. This happens even if they started out at the same speed, and one accelerated. Which one accelerated would make no difference to the result.

No matter how fast someone else sees a rocket travel, it is always at rest with respect to itself. It always sees itself in its usual rest-frame shape.

Comment: Is there experimental evidence for this? What if different points on the same object have different resting reference frames while accelerating?

Comment: If you are talking about accelerating frames of reference, you need general relativity instead of special relativity. Things get more complicated. Of course, even in classical physics, an object will change shape if one part of it has a different rest frame than another. That would mean they are moving at different velocities.